# Javascript in Gridview causes other event to fire?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0, nested

I'm roughly following the concept from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView). To simulate a nested GridView.
It looks like this:

[image: buttons to display detailsRow]

Basically I'm creating a second row which is `display:none` and want to toggle it using JavaScript.

JavaScript and aspx code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function detailsToggle(Company_ID) {
        try {
            detail_row = document.getElementById('detailsRow_' + Company_ID);
            parent_row = document.getElementById('parentRow_' + Company_ID);
            img = parent_row.cells[0].firstChild;

            if (detail_row.className !== 'hidden') {
                detail_row.className = detail_row.className + ' hidden';
                img.src = '../Images/icons/+.gif';
            }
            else {
                detail_row.className = detail_row.className.replace(/\bhidden\b/, '');
                img.src = '../Images/icons/-.gif';
            }
        }
        catch(ex) { alert(ex); }
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden 
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<asp:GridView ID="gvLegalEntityBrowser" DataKeyNames="Company_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvLegalEntityBrowser_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="pagingIndexChanged"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25" AllowSorting="false">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <%--Placeholder --%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyCode" HeaderText="CompanyCode" SortExpression="CompanyCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No data</EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

... and my apsx.cs RowDataBound Method:

```
//Idea from : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView
protected void gvLegalEntityBrowser_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = e.Row as GridViewRow;
        Int64 iCompanyID = 0;   //Get Company_ID for Legal Entity Row
        iCompanyID = System.Convert.ToInt64(gvLegalEntityBrowser.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex]["Company_ID"]);
        GridView gvLegalEntityRelation = new GridView();
        gvRow.ID = "parentRow_" + iCompanyID;
        gvRow.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;   //Set HTML ID element = control.ID

        //Add javascript toggle button to each row
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton toggleButton = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton();
        toggleButton.ID = "btnToggle_" + iCompanyID;
        toggleButton.ImageUrl = "../Images/icons/+.gif";
        toggleButton.OnClientClick = "detailsToggle(" + (iCompanyID) + ")";
        gvRow.Cells[0].Controls.Add(toggleButton);
        toggleButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","this.style.cursor='hand'");
        toggleButton.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.cursor='default'");

        using (dsLegalEntitiesTableAdapters.View_LegalEntityRelationCountTableAdapter daLERelCount = new dsLegalEntitiesTableAdapters.View_LegalEntityRelationCountTableAdapter())
        {
            //Set Details Data Source
            gvLegalEntityRelation.DataSource = daLERelCount.GetRelationsDataByCompanyID(iCompanyID);
            gvLegalEntityRelation.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

            GridViewRow detailsgvRow = new GridViewRow(gvRow.RowIndex + 1, -1, DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            detailsgvRow.CssClass = "hidden";
            detailsgvRow.ID = "detailsRow_" + iCompanyID;
            detailsgvRow.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;    //Set HTML ID element = control.ID
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.ColumnSpan = 4;
            cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            cell.Controls.Add(gvLegalEntityRelation);
            detailsgvRow.Cells.Add(cell);
            ((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.Add(detailsgvRow);

            gvLegalEntityRelation.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

The JavaScript works fine, and I even see the correct Result for a split second:

[image]

... but the the parent GridView rebuilds into something like this:

[image: After javascript executes]

**Q: Does anyone have an Idea what may be causing the GridView to rebuild??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... the problem was actually quite basic. A colleague pointed this out to me.

I used an ImageButton to expand the inner table. The .NET image button has Click handler and ClientClick handler. Click tells what to do on PostBack, and ClientClick passes on to JavaScript.

Apparently, even if I don't define a target function for Click, the page still does a Post-Back. Thus first the javascript works, and then the page does a post-back, messing up the page.

**Solution**: exchange ImageButton for a simple image with click-event for javascript.